# I am getting an error while doing SFTP

Tags: sftp

I am trying to send a file using SFTP. But getting below error when connecting:

```
/opt/qrmftp/.ssh/config line 2: Bad SSH2 Mac spec 'hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha256@ssh.com'.
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this remove these ciphers and MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha256 lines from /etc/ssh/sshd_config and then restarting sshd service.